# Python Pandas How to Assign JSON Values to a Pandas DF

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, api

I am requesting data from an API like this:

```
output = requests.get(url=url, auth=oauth, headers=headers, data=payload)
output_data_test = output.json()

output_data_test["customers"][0]["id"]
'1'
```

When I do this, the value does not get assigned:

```
combined_output_temp_df = output_data_test["customers"][0]["id"]

combined_output_temp_df
Empty DataFrame
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I created my dataframe:

```
combined_output_temp_df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = [
        "id",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "middle_initial",
        "email",
        ### - Preferences
        "preference_email_invoices",
        "preference_print_invoices",
        "preference_exclude_from_insurance_auto_enroll_on",
        ###
        "username",
        "created_at",,
        "blocked_payments",
        ### - Phone Numbers
        "phone_number_id",
        "phone_number_primary",
        ### - Mailing Address
        "mailing_address_id",
        "mailing_address_address1",
        "mailing_address_address2",
        "mailing_address_city",
        "mailing_address_state",
        "mailing_address_latitude",
        ### - Addresses
        "address_id",
        "address_address1", 
        "address_address2",
        "address_city",
        "address_state",
        "address_invalid_data",
        "address_label"
        ###
        ]
    )
```

Here is roughly what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    'customers': [
        {
            'id': '1', 
            'first_name': 'James', 
            'last_name': 'Test', 
            'middle_initial': '', 
            'email': 'jamesemail@test.com', 
            'preferences': {
                'email_invoices': False, 
                'print_invoices': False, 
                'exclude_from_insurance_auto_enroll_on': None
                }, 
                
                'username': jamestesting, 
                'created_at': '2021-03-11T13:00:00.404-05:00', 
                'blocked_payments': False, 
                'phone_numbers': [
                    {
                        'id': '234234asdf', 
                        'primary': True
                    }, 
                    {
                        'id': '8438c19a', 
                        'primary': False
                    }
                ], 'mailing_address': {
                    'id': '431fe0b2', 
                    'address1': '15777 Fake Blvd', 
                    'address2': 'Lot 196', 
                    'city': 'Testing', 
                    'state': 'TX', 
                    'latitude': None
                }, 'addresses': [
                    {
                        'id': '431fe0b2', 
                        'address1': '157 whatever', 
                        'address2': 'Lot 196', 
                        'city': 'Sacramento', 
                        'state': 'NY', 
                        'invalid_data': False, 
                        'label': 'Home'
                    }
                ]
          }
   ]
```

}

Some customers have multiple phone numbers, some have 0 phone numbers. Same with mailing address and other attributes not found here. When I tried to use explode, it gave me an error message

Comment: Based on the code you shared - you are not creating a dataframe.

Comment: I am creating it earlier in the code. One of the columns is called "id".

Comment: You are not passing data to `pd.DataFrame`, so it is creating an empty df.  Do you want to load `output_data_test` into pandas with those 5 columns? If so, please share a few sample of `output_data_test`.

Comment: I just want the ID column

Comment: `df = pd.json_normalize(output_data_test, record_path=['customers'])[['id']]` ?

Comment: Some of the JSON has values inside of the attributes, i.e. phone_numbers:[ {id...,primary...},{id...primary}], There are multiple attributes like this, so I'm trying to get creative here.

Comment: Multiple attributes doesn't matter so much. You can still extract what you want. But in any case, you should share the JSON data in question and also the expected df.  Otherwise, it is very hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: you will have to store the whole dataframe due to symmetry, you can just set rest of the properties to be null.

Comment: That's roughly what everything looks like. Just posted my actual dataframe and data returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the column of the dataframe where you want that string to get added / replaced. There are two ways of doing it either pass it as an argument when you are creating the dataframe, or if you are getting the value after creating the dateframe you can assign it to the corresponding column.

See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Following is the pseudocode:

```
import pandas as pd

test_var = '1' 
print(test_var)

new_df = pd.DataFrame( [test_var], dtype="string" )
print(new_df)

new_df['col'] = '2'
print(new_df)
```

For multiple columns you can do something along the following lines:

```
combined_output_temp_df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = [
        "id",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "middle_initial",
        "email"
        ]
    )

combined_output_temp_df = [ 'test_id', 'test_fn', 'test_ln', 'test_middle', 'email' ]

print(combined_output_temp_df);
```

Comment: That's not working either, maybe something is wrong with how I created the dataframe. Will edit my original code to include this.

Comment: Edited my original post to add that.

Comment: I have added bit more pseudocode, have not tested it but should work. You also should define the datatype of all the columns, or if they are different you can use df.astype - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving you a complete answer but this could give you a starter.

First use `json_normalize` on top level to create a DataFrame.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(output_data_test, record_path=['customers'])
```

Then, if you need a single phone number or addresses per row,

```
df = df.explode('phone_numbers')
df = df.explode('addresses')
```

Then you can flatten the phone_numbers/addresses columns.

Or alternatively,

```
df = pd.json_normalize(output_data_test, record_path=['customers'])
df_phone = pd.json_normalize(output_data_test['customers'], record_path=['phone_numbers'], meta=['id'], record_prefix='phone_numbers_')
df = df.merge(df_phone, on='id', how='left')
```

Then do the similar thing with addresses.